# Insert special characters in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

So I have a textbox and I want to add some text( without deleting the one I already have) by clicking a button.. is that possible?

The text I'll be adding will be some html special characters code like é to show a "é"...

or maybe do the reverse, like I write a "é" and then when I submit it changes to é this way it will be easier to the user

Thanks in advance

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: you can use += instead of just = to add, not to replace the current text :) and what about your special characters? they doesn't get displayed correctly?

Comment: Please, don't call them "special" characters. They are healthy as all the other characters... They want your love... Simply they aren't from the dominating ASCII race :-) But we aren't racist on SO :-) :-)

Comment: @mplungjan I have try something like this :http://jsfiddle.net/T6Myh/

Comment: @xanatos Love your answer man xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Addtext" onclick="addText()" />
<script>
    function addText() {
        document.getElementById('txt').value += "sometextàéèìòù";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I already try something like it but doesn't work.. :s
here: http://jsfiddle.net/T6Myh/

Comment: you forgot to put the closing script tag there "</script>"

Comment: And you forgot to space it correctly, so it wasn't visible in your example :-) I have added some letters with diacritics.

Answer (score 0):

On the button click, simply append the character you require to the string that is already in the text box.  An example of this is [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?34869-Adding-Text-Into-Textbox-with-JavaScript)