# How do you insert a special character into a text input at an arbitrary position on button click?

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked and answered several times [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076895/insert-special-characters-in-textbox). However none of them address inserting at an arbitrary point.

So if you have a text input or textarea and a button for some symbol that isn't on the keyboard (e.g. pi) or a button that if text is highlighted you add an accent or some other diacritical mark. How would you insert that at the current caret position or selection? This will not necessarily be at the end if the user moves the cursor and when the mouse is clicked you lose focus on the input which will remove the caret or selection.

```
<input id="formula" type="text">
<button onclick="insertIntoFormula">π</button>
```

Comment: Where is your source code to return/target the selected text within the input?

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eaozwuv6/) might be of some use to you?

Comment: @NewToJS this inserts the symbol at the beginning of the string (not at caret position) because of the problem of the input losing focus. Which is the problem I'm not sure how to get around.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. Not sure how I missed that in your question description. I'm not sure it will be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`.selectionStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart) (the starting index of the highlighted text) and [`.selectionEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionEnd) (the ending index of the highlighted text). If it's just a cursor, they'll both just return its position.

```js
function insertIntoFormula(specialChar) {
    const textarea = document.getElementById('formula');
    const insertStartPoint = textarea.selectionStart;
    const insertEndPoint = textarea.selectionEnd;
    let value = textarea.value;
 
    // text before cursor/highlighted text + special character + text after cursor/highlighted text
    value = value.slice(0, insertStartPoint) + specialChar + value.slice(insertEndPoint);
    textarea.value = value;
}
```

```html
<input id="formula" type="text">
<!-- remember to actually pass the special character -->
<!-- (you *could* just get the innerText of the triggering button but I wouldn't recommend it) -->
<button onclick="insertIntoFormula('π')">π</button>
<button onclick="insertIntoFormula('é')">é</button>
```

Comment: Do you know who this retains the caret position even when focus is switched to the button?

Comment: @qw3n You can run the above code snippet and see how it works. It will remember the caret position when focus is switched to the button. (However, on subsequent clicks it always seems to reset caret position to the start. You'd have to add some extra code for it to remember if you expect users to often be clicking the button twice-in-a-row.)